# Generate LaTeX and PDF from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, pdf, latex, tex

I want to generate a LaTeX document from Objective-C and compile it with pdfLatex so that I have an PDF in the end.

Is there a SDK to do this, or do I need to write to file some LaTeX code from a NSString and run pdflatex with a NSTask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some work has been done on calling out to TeX.  There's the [TeX daemon](http://www.pytex.org/texd/), which is part of [PyTeX](http://www.pytex.org), and which looks like it's doing something like what you need.  I've seen this system working, but haven't used it myself and I'm not sure of its current status.

If, on the other hand, you're after doing this programmatically in order to get equation bitmaps (or something like that, which your question vaguely suggests), then you might be interested in the `dvipng` or `dvi2bitmap` libraries, which skip postscript/PDF entirely.

As a general point, when doing things like this in the past, I've found it useful to arrange that the LaTeX I generate is pretty high-level, and the detailed layout is deferred to a class or style that you write yourself.  That means that you can tune the details of the LaTeX layout while mentally in a LaTeX mode, which ends up less confusing in the end.

Comment: Generally I want to generate an invoice as PDF with the data entered in the application. I found out there is a PDF-kit framework but because I have experience with LaTeX I thought it would be more flexible.

Comment: Well, in that case, I think the best thing to do would be to have your application generate high-level output, perhaps with a custom documentclass or package, and deal with the formatting in the implementation of that class/package.  That leaves your application handling its core logic, nicely decoupled from the (conceptually separate) formatting logic.

Comment: Thank you for al the help, I will try.